# Ionic 3 - Añadir una directiva a un (click)=""

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Mi duda es que estoy haciendo una APP con `Ionic 3` y en el `TypeScript` tengo una variable que quiero meter en el `(click)=""` pero no sé como hacerlo, estas son las formas que he intentado pero me da error.

```
[(click)]="{{type.name}}"
([click])="{{type.name}}"
[click]="{{type.name}}"
(click)="{{type.name}}"
```

Ninguna funciona. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo vas a meter un valor el un evento? ¿Qué pretendes hacer con el valor de esa variable?

Comment: Lo tendrías que poner como (click)=mifuncion(miVariable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(click)='myFunction(valor)';
```

click lanza un evento. por lo que llama a una función, ya en la función recoges tu variable y la usas como quieres.
otro error es el uso de {{}}.

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy trabajando dentro de on ng-for y necesito mandar un parametro del html al ts pero dentro de AQUI no me deja poner {{dato}} como le mando exactamente el nompre expecifico que tiene ese bucle por que por cada vuelta cambia y yo solo necesito mandarle el que hagan click.

```
(click)="myFunction(AQUI)"
```

Comment: {{dato}} no tiene que ir entre {{}} tiene que ir solo. en el aqui. `(click)="myFunction({{dato}})"` mal  //   `(click)="myFunction(dato)" ` bien